# VScroll on Panel is not scrolling. Panel has 200 height and buttons for 2000 pxs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, scroll, panel

Problem is simple, how can I code VScroll for panel with lots of controls on it ? I can't find event for up/down/drag...

I want ONLY vertical scroll as horizontal scroll/auto scroll will destroy whole look of GUI (each control on panel is prepared to fit other controls on other panels).

I know how to use autoscroll, please do not propose that as that's simple won't fit into my specification. It has to be VScroll control....

Comment: Your question is unreadable.  Just set the AutoScroll property to True.  If that also displays a horizontal scrollbar then you have no other option than to make the panel wider or move the controls.  Trying to make the horizontal scrollbar disappear will not work.

Comment: Like I said because of how this list looks I can't use autosize (doesn't matter why, I can't because it would destroy whole look) !!!